# check RAM,page file, /PAE, /3GB, SQL server memory using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am a powershell novice.

After days of searching....

I have put together a small powershell script (as below) to check page file, /PAE switch, /3GB switch, SQL server max RAM, min RAM.
I am running this on 1 server.

If I want to run it on many servers (from a .txt) file, How can I change it ?
How can I change it to search boot.ini file's contents for a given server?

```
clear
$strComputer="."

$PageFile=Get-WmiObject Win32_PageFile -ComputerName $strComputer
Write-Host "Page File Size in MB: " ($PageFile.Filesize/(1024*1024))


$colItems=Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory -Namespace root\CIMv2 -ComputerName $strComputer
$total=0
foreach ($objItem in $colItems)
{
    $total=$total+ $objItem.Capacity
}


$isPAEEnabled =Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer
Write-Host "Is PAE Enabled: " $isPAEEnabled.PAEEnabled 

Write-Host "Is /3GB Enabled: " | Get-Content C:\boot.ini | Select-String "/3GB" -Quiet  
# how can I change to search boot.ini file's contents on $strComputer

$smo = new-object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $strSQLServer
$memSrv = $smo.information.physicalMemory
$memMin = $smo.configuration.minServerMemory.runValue
$memMax = $smo.configuration.maxServerMemory.runValue


## DBMS
Write-Host "Server RAM available:       " -noNewLine
Write-Host "$memSrv MB" -fore "blue"
Write-Host "SQL memory Min:             " -noNewLine
Write-Host "$memMin MB " 
Write-Host "SQL memory Max:             " -noNewLine
Write-Host "$memMax MB"
```

Any comments how this can be improved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind though, that boot.ini isn't used anymore for some time now. For any recent OS this will just yield nothing.

Comment: If boot.ini is not used in some OS, where do we include /PAE and /3GB switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you would like just to check the boot.ini file you could use `Get-Content` (in case you will not have problems with credentials)

```
# create a test file with server names
@"
server1
server2
"@ | set-content c:\temp\serversso.txt

# read the file and get the content
get-content c:\temp\serversso.txt | 
    % { get-content "\\$_\c`$\boot.ini" } |
    Select-String "/3GB" -Quiet
```

Later if you add some stuff that will be needed to run on remote computer then you will need to use remoting and basically `Invoke-Command`. Recently two resources appeared that touch remoting:

- [Administrator's Guid to Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/4908.aspx)
- [Series on PowerShell remoting](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?tag=powershell-remoting) by Ravikanth Chaganti that starts [here](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1025)